# Simple Linux HTTP proxy server, which itself can use proxy servers

Tags: linux, networking, authentication, proxy

Some programs (like Chromium) does not like username and password in `http_proxy` environment variable.

For this, it could be useful to use intermediate proxy server, which "converts" authenticated proxy to localhost-only unauthenticated one.

Workaround in form of `proxychains 3proxy` fails to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using Privoxy for this goal : you can add http auth header on each query, then use https://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/config.html#FORWARD to forward requests to the other proxy.

Then configure Chromium to use local privoxy instance.

For example, I suppose you have the following setup :

```
http_proxy=http://user:password@your.proxy.your.domain:8080
```

Then, you can setup Privoxy to forward everything to your proxy :

`forward / your.proxy.your.domain:8080`

And add a custom filter in *user.action* file, to add http authentication header on each proxied request :

```
{{alias}}
  proxy-auth = +add-header{Proxy-Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXX}

{ proxy-auth }  
  /
```

XXXXXX = login:password string base64 encoded

Finally, change *http_proxy* variable to use privoxy (without login/password, because they're added via filter) :

```
    http_proxy=http://localhost:8118
```

Comment: `Privoxy itself does not support proxy authentication, but can allow clients to authenticate against Privoxy's parent proxy.` -> So how can Privoxy workaround non-support of authentication from http_proxy variable in Chromium?